# Scrapy: Spider optimization

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrap an e-commerce web site, and I'm doing it in 2 steps.

This website has a structure like this:

- The homepage has the links to the family-items and subfamily-items pages
- Each family & subfamily page has a list of products paginated

Right now I have 2 spiders:

- **GeneralSpider** to get the homepage links and store them
- **ItemSpider** to get elements from each page

I'm completely new to Scrapy, I'm following some tutorials to achieve this. I'm wondering how complex can be the parse functions and how rules works. My spiders right now looks like:

## GeneralSpider:

```
class GeneralSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'domain'
    allowed_domains = ['domain.org']
    start_urls = ['http://www.domain.org/home']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = LinksItem()
        links['content'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='h45F23']").extract()
        return links
```

## ItemSpider:

```
class GeneralSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'domain'
    allowed_domains = ['domain.org']
    f = open("urls.txt")
    start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    # Each URL in the file has pagination if it has more than 30 elements
    # I don't know how to paginate over each URL
    f.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        item = ShopItem()
        item['name'] = response.xpath("//h1[@id='u_name']").extract()
        item['description'] = response.xpath("//h3[@id='desc_item']").extract()
        item['prize'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='price_eur']").extract()
        return item
```

- Wich is the best way to make the spider follow the pagination of an url ?
- If the pagination is **JQuery**, meaning there is no *GET variable* in the URL, Would be possible to follow the pagination ?
- Can I have different "***rules***" in the same spider to scrap different parts of the page ? or is better to  have the spiders *specialized*, each spider focused in one thing?

I've also googled looking for any book related with Scrapy, but it seems there isn't any finished book yet, or at least I couldn't find one.

- Does anyone know if some **Scrapy** book that will be released soon ?

## Edit:

This 2 URL's fits for this example. In the *Eroski Home* page you can get the URL's to the products page.

In the products page you have a list of items paginated (*Eroski Items*):

- URL to get Links:  [Eroski Home](http://www.compraonline.grupoeroski.com/supermercado/home.jsp)
- URL to get Items: [Eroski Fruits](http://www.compraonline.grupoeroski.com/supermercado/2059698-Alimentos-Frescos/2059699-Frutas/)

In the *Eroski Fruits* page, the pagination of the items seems to be JQuery/AJAX, because more items are shown when you scroll down, is there a way to get all this items with **Scrapy** ?

Comment: Sharing the link to an actual website would make it easier to answer. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I added an edit, check both urls

Comment: Never used scrapy so I can't answer specifically. You may be able to find more examples of scraping which use standard libraries like `httplib`, `urllib`, `urllib2` to send queries, and `BeautifulSoup` to parse the content of web pages thereby obtained. Quickly looking at your Fruit page, I see that I am able to obtain further items by adding `page=2` in the url e.g. `http://www.compraonline.grupoeroski.com/supermercado/ajax/listProducts.jsp?page=2&categoria=2059698&grupo=2059699&familia=2059701` so you could loop until you get an empty page (it's the case with 3 here)

Comment: @etna thanks for your help ! I'd try this solution with Scrapy. I know I can use BeautifulSoup, urllib and even Selenium, but I want to use spiders

Comment: No problem, I just meant to provide an alternative given the absence of answer so far. Also I expect the `page‌​=n` to answer your pagination issue (beware when copy pasting the url I gave in your internet browser/code: the line break messes with `page=2` (two characters are added and thus must be suppressed))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which is the best way to make the spider follow the pagination of an url ?

This is very site-specific and depends on how the pagination is implemented.

> If the pagination is JQuery, meaning there is no GET variable in the URL, Would be possible to follow the pagination ?

This is exactly your use case - the pagination is made via additional AJAX calls that you can simulate inside your Scrapy spider.

> Can I have different "rules" in the same spider to scrape different parts of the page ? or is better to have the spiders specialized, each spider focused in one thing?

Yes, the "rules" mechanism that a `CrawlSpider` provides is a very powerful piece of technology - it is highly configurable - you can have multiple rules, some of them would follow specific links that match specific criteria, or located in a specific section of a page. Having a single spider with multiple rules should be preferred comparing to having multiple spiders.

Speaking about your specific use-case, here is the idea:

- make a `rule` to follow categories and subcategories in the navigation menu of the home page - this is there `restrict_xpaths` would help
- in the callback, for every category or subcategory `yield` a `Request` that would mimic the AJAX request sent by your browser when you open a category page
- in the AJAX response handler (callback) parse the available items and `yield` an another `Request` for the same category/subcategory but increasing the `page` GET parameter (getting next page)

Example working implementation:

```
import re
import urllib

import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class ProductItem(scrapy.Item):
    description = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()


class GrupoeroskiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'grupoeroski'
    allowed_domains = ['compraonline.grupoeroski.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.compraonline.grupoeroski.com/supermercado/home.jsp']

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="navmenu"]'), callback='parse_categories')
    ]

    def parse_categories(self, response):
        pattern = re.compile(r'/(\d+)\-\w+')
        groups = pattern.findall(response.url)
        params = {'page': 1, 'categoria': groups.pop(0)}

        if groups:
            params['grupo'] = groups.pop(0)
        if groups:
            params['familia'] = groups.pop(0)

        url = 'http://www.compraonline.grupoeroski.com/supermercado/ajax/listProducts.jsp?' + urllib.urlencode(params)
        yield scrapy.Request(url,
                             meta={'params': params},
                             callback=self.parse_products,
                             headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})

    def parse_products(self, response):
        for product in response.xpath('//div[@class="product_element"]'):
            item = ProductItem()
            item['description'] = product.xpath('.//span[@class="description_1"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['price'] = product.xpath('.//div[@class="precio_line"]/p/text()').extract()[0]
            yield item

        params = response.meta['params']
        params['page'] += 1

        url = 'http://www.compraonline.grupoeroski.com/supermercado/ajax/listProducts.jsp?' + urllib.urlencode(params)
        yield scrapy.Request(url,
                             meta={'params': params},
                             callback=self.parse_products,
                             headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})
```

Hope this is a good starting point for you.

---

> Does anyone know if some Scrapy book that will be released soon?

Nothing specific that I can recall.

<sup>Though I heard that some publisher has some plans to may be release a book about web-scraping, but I'm not supposed to tell you that.</sup>

Comment: After reading all in detail, I'm very very grateful, You saved me a lot of hours digging information. Your explanation is awesome ! I owe you a big one !